# Как сравнить производительность двух программ

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, имеются две разные программы написанные на языке C++. Обе программы реализуют одну и туже задачу, но разными способами. Требуется сравнить их производительность (скорость работы, использование памяти). Прошу вас объяснить мне как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для определения и сравнения скорости работы какой-то части программы, нужно замерить время ее выполнения. Чтобы добиться статистической точности, нужно эту часть вставить в цикл и проделать много раз. Время можно замерить стандартными методами, например, функцией clock. Подробнее смотрите справочную информацию к Вашему компилятору или среде разработки. Кроме того, на разных платформах есть методы более точного замера времени.

Answer (score 3):

Можно вставлять измерители в программу (если есть исходники), а можно воспользоваться внешними средствами.

Если речь идет о Linux, то для начала можно посмотреть на команду GNU time (обычно /usr/bin/time). Подробная информация в manpage ([например здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=time&category=1&russian=2))

Запускайте свои программы с разными данными через нее и сравнивайте результаты.

Answer (score 2):

Советую почитать Кормена - Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ.

Если не ошибаюсь, первая глава посвящена именно этой теме.

UPD: Как-бы: "Автор - полное название":
Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ. Издание 2-е, скачать Томас Кормен, Чарльз Лейзерсон, Рональд Ривест.

Comment: Дайте полное название книги, а лучше линк на скачивание.